# Clarification needed regarding ResultIterator in TessBaseApi

Tags: android, tesseract

I've been working on Tesseract for Android. Is it necessary to call baseApi.getUTF8Text() before getting a ResultIterator? Because, `baseApi.getResultIterator()` returns null if I call `baseApi.getUTF8Text()` after `baseApi.getResultIterator()`.